# select * in 3 database with wildcard as parameter

Tags: sql, pdo, inner-join

im using wild card like this

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id2 = $_POST['id2'];
$id3 = $_POST['id3'];
$id4 = $_POST['id4'];
if( isset($id) && isset($id2) && isset($id3) && isset($id4))
$stmt = $dbh->prepare........
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%" . $id . "%");
$stmt->bindValue(2, "%" . $id2 . "%");
$stmt->bindValue(3, "%" . $id3 . "%");
$stmt->bindValue(4, "%" . $id4 . "%");
```

I want to get all entry in 3 databases using 4 parameters with join like this

```
basic_tbl t1 
INNER JOIN tour_tbl t2 
on t1.id = t2=id 
INNER JOIN tour_address_tbl t3 
on t1.id = t3.id 
WHERE t1.id like ? 
AND t2.id2 like ? 
AND t1.id3 like ? 
AND t1.id4 like ?
```

The problem is i get multiple but duplicate data how to avoid or fix this problem

```
basic_tbl
sysid
id
lastname
firstname

tour_tbl
sysid
id
basic_id
kind

tour_address_tbl
sysid
tour_id
address
```

Comment: Whith out seeing the database struction and sample Date we can't help you.

Comment: wait give me a minute\

Comment: which table you want to avoid to be duplicated?

Comment: actually in my result each field has duplicate

Comment: Are you sure that is your query? I'm sure there is errors on it.

Comment: yes it is i fix it now